# BinaryFormatter handles more cases than XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, serialization

Is the statement in the question correct?

For example it seems that there is no way to serialize the code below (array of mixed types) with XmlSerializer whereas BinaryFormatter works just fine:

```
using System.IO;

[Serializiable]
class ParentCls
{
    int k;
}

[Serializiable]
class X : ParentCls
{
    string name = "foobar";
}

[Serializiable]
class Y : ParentCls
{
    double price = 32.0;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ParentCls[] data = new ParentCls[] { new X(), new Y() };
        using (Stream stream = File.Open("tmp.bin", FileMode.Create))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Are there cases where XmlSerialiser can do what BinaryFormatter can not do
(i.e. where using XmlSerialiser is the only way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not correct. Depends on many circumstances. In some cases, the `BinaryFormatter` is more convenient, in others the `XmlSerializer`.

---

`XmlSerializer` can serialize an array of mixed types. For this you need to use the [XmlInclude](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute in the following way.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(X))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Y))]
public class ParentCls
{
    public int k;
}

public class X : ParentCls
{
    public string name = "foobar";
}

public class Y : ParentCls
{
    public double price = 32.0;
}
```

Please note that you must use the public access modifier, that is a serious limitation of the `XmlSerializer`.

Example usage

```
ParentCls[] data = new ParentCls[] { new X(), new Y() };
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ParentCls[]));

using (Stream stream = File.Open("tmp.xml", FileMode.Create))
    xs.Serialize(stream, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there are structural limitations - where a type cannot be represented by either serialization technology. However, there are scenarios where xml serialization is *easier* than with binary serialization...for this reason: binary serialization carries type information and xml serialization does not. Xml serialization is closer to so-called duck typing in this respect. Yes, the element names and namespaces provide hints, but not demands.

Why would this be important? The most often used situation is where the serialization contract matches one type on a client and another *completely different* type on a server...one that shares the serialization format (same type name and members). This is not uncommon with the data contract serializer (an xml serializer) and WCF. Worth noting, in scenarios where you have to support data contracts for several versions of a data contract, xml serialization provides far simpler solutions. Here's a pretty good overview of data contract [serialization strategies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384251.aspx) for some ideas.

Sure, you can implement surrogates and various mapping techniques with most serialization technologies. Xml serialization is just more purpose-built for these scenarios...and in particular, data contract serialization is crazy good for these situations.